# A clickonce application was published with unchecked "application should check for updates" setting. Is there a way to update these settings somehow?

Tags: .net, clickonce

Our applicaiton is installed to some 50 users, now the version which is lastly updated for them does not check the updates. But I still need to update the app.  Is there a way to do this without reinstalling for them?

Answer (score 1):

It depends if your application is runnable locally or only online. If it's only online, simply pushing new build (with increased version) to the web will force update next time they'll run the app. If both locally and online, you're out of luck.